# How do I start/stop mysql in XAMPP?

Tags: 11.10, mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

I installed XAMPP. Now the problems are

- I can not start mysql
  `root@ubuntu:/# sudo /opt/lampp/lampp startmysql`
  `XAMPP: Starting MySQL...`
  `XAMPP: Couldn't start MySQL!`
- I can not put my projects so i can test it
  **/opt/lampp/htdocs/**
  root@ubuntu:~# cp -r /home/sou/socialnetwork/* /opt/lampp/htdocs/SocialNetwork
  cp: cannot stat `/home/sou/socialnetwork/*': No such file or directory

root@ubuntu:~# cp -r `/home/sou/socialnetwork/*` `/opt/lampp/htdocs/SocialNetwork`
-bash: /home/sou/socialnetwork/*: No such file or directory
-bash: /opt/lampp/htdocs/SocialNetwork: No such file or directory
cp: missing file operand
Try `cp --help' for more information.

- phpMyAdmin can not work

MySQL said: Documentation
2002 - The server is not responding (or the local MySQL server's socket is not correctly configured)
Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed.

I just startted with Ubuntu 1day ago, so i dont know the staffs required to start XAMPP properly. please guide me !

## **What i need**

- To start/stop MySQL
- To open the directory and copy required files to it
- To start phpMyAdmin

Comment: Why did you install XAMPP? Everything it provides is available from the standard repositories.

Comment: what do you mean by `standard repositories` ? i got 11.04, i also searched in Software center and tried to install from the console also, all failed

Comment: @Sourav You can install Apache, MySQL, PHP, etc using `tasksel`. `sudo apt-get install tasksel && sudo tasksel install lamp-server`

Answer (score 6):

XAMPP itself isn't in the repos but MySQL, PHP, Apache and everything else that is included in XAMPP has a package. It can be done as simple as this:

```
sudo apt-get install lamp-server^
```

<sup>**Note:** The `^` on the end isn't a typo - it's how we denote tasks.</sup>

XAMPP includes some other things you you probably don't need but you can install most of a command like this (I suggest you only install the things you want, for performance):

```
sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin proftpd-basic openssl php5-ming php5-gd sqlite3 php5-sqlite php5-mcrypt webalizer php-pear
```

That affords you a fairly standard stack. The major differences between this and XAMPP are:

- These are set up for production use - with fairly secure defaults
- Apache and MySQL are set to run on boot - XAMPP runs when you tell it to.
- You will get security updates for all these packages through Ubuntu's updater
- You might have to fine tune some of the configuration for your needs

Once you're at that point, you can follow [the standard documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheMySQLPHP). It might be a little old but most of it should hold true.

Comment: root@ubuntu:~# sudo apt-get install tasksel
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package tasksel
root@ubuntu:~# sudo tasksel install lamp-server
sudo: tasksel: command not found
root@ubuntu:~# sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin proftpd-basic openssl php5-ming php5-gd sqlite3 php5-sqlite php5-mcrypt webalizer php-pear
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package proftpd-basic
E: Unable to locate package php5-gd ...

Comment: Run `sudo apt-get update` and try these again. If you're still not able to install something as basic as `tasksel` you've got fairly large problems, completely separate from this thread.

Answer (score 0):

To install XAMPP you need to log in as `root` and then everything works fine, sudo-i is not an option in this case, it still shows some functions as deactivated.

Answer (score -1):

download EasyLAMPP [Here](https://github.com/soekarmana/EasyLAMPP/zipball/master)

extract and run the script

this script automate XAMPP for linux installation, eg. extracting, configuring permission and adding Control Panel & XAMPP Htdocs Launcher 

you can read the full instruction [Here](http://translate.google.com/translate?sl=id&tl=en&js=n&prev=_t&hl=id&ie=UTF-8&layout=2&eotf=1&u=http://wayanngeblog.blogspot.com/2011/11/cara-mudah-instalasi-xampp-for-linux.html)

Answer (score -2):

Why don't you install xampp control panel like of windows. here is the  full tutorial of it . http://freshtutorial.com/add-gui-xampp-control-panel-ubuntu/ it will makes your work lot easier